# Methods to simplify $\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\frac{\ln (\cos (x))\ln (\cos (y))}{\sin (x)+\sin (y)}\:dx\:dy.$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, multiple-integral, trigonometric-integrals

I want to evaluate:
$$\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\frac{\ln \left(\cos \left(x\right)\right)\ln \left(\cos \left(y\right)\right)}{\sin \left(x\right)+\sin \left(y\right)}\:dx\:dy.$$
But I've no idea on how to simplify this into $1$ integral. I tried to write as follows:
$$\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\ln \left(\cos \left(y\right)\right)\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\csc \left(x\right)\ln \left(\cos \left(x\right)\right)\:dx\:dy$$
$$-\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\ln \left(\cos \left(y\right)\right)\sin \left(y\right)\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\frac{\ln \left(\cos \left(x\right)\right)}{\sin \left(x\right)\left(\sin \left(x\right)+\sin \left(y\right)\right)}\:dx\:dy.$$
But I still have trouble with the $2$nd double integral.

Comment: Please try to specify the problem more clearly. Titles like 'A problem', 'How to solve it' and similar do not allow other users who may have the same kind of problem to search for it and find a solution. You may also want to find more hints at [How do I ask a good question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) in our [Help center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help)/[Asking](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/asking).

Comment: @CiaPan I tried to put the integral in the title but it exceeded the amount of characters.

Comment: AFAIK LaTeX/MathJax expressions are not text-searchable, so that wouldn't help, either. May be someting like 'Integrating a ratio of composition of logarithimic and trigonometric functions' will do...? :)

Comment: Oops, made a typo in my previous comment, beware of superfluous 'i' in 'logarithmic'. :D

Comment: I guess that'd be sort of better, by the way, latex does help in searching problems, for example [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/).

Comment: I've been working on your integral. I've got a new representación but I don't know if you need to calculate its value or only simplify (as you say in title). This new way could be useful for calculation. It would also be interesting to know the context in which the integral is found cause it can be useful for handling it.

Comment: @popi Please show us what you've got, I'm sure it'll be useful.

Comment: For what it's worth, using the 2D change of variables $\left(x,y\right)=\left(t+u,t-u\right)$ the integral can be rewritten as $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\mathrm{d}u\int_{u}^{\frac{\pi}{2}-u}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{2\ln{\left(\cos{\left(t+u\right)}\right)}\ln{\left(\cos{\left(t-u\right)}\right)}}{\sin{\left(t\right)}\cos{\left(u\right)}}$.